# Android RSS Feed

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rss, helper

i am creating an app for my final year project at uni.. i am trying to get an rss feed working.. My issue at the moment is that i created a project (RSSActivity) and got the RSS feeds to work. I then copy and pasted all the files (5 classes and 2 layouts) into the appropriate places. There were a few errors: R cannot be found, but this was easily fixed by changing the package to that of the project (football_app). What i am tring to do is be able to click on a button called 'News' and the news appears.. the problem that i am have is that the when i now click on the 'News' button, it say 'Unfortunately football app has stopped'.. i have tried every single class in the intent, and changed the intent activity name appropriately.. can  anyone help me.. code below...

```
 /////////////// HttpFeedSource.java

    package com.julian.football_app;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    class HttpFeedSource implements FeedSource {

        protected static final String URL = "http://www.skysports.com/rss/0,20514,11661,00.xml";

        public List<RSSItem> getFeed() {
            List<RSSItem> itemList = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();

            NewsParser parser = new NewsParser(URL);
            parser.parse();
            NewsParser.RssFeed feed = parser.getFeed();

            for (NewsParser.Item i : feed.getItems()) {
                itemList.add(new RSSItem(i.getUrl(), i.getTitle(), i.getDescription(), i.getimageUrl()));
            }
            return itemList;
        }

    }


    ////////////////////// FeedSource.java

        package com.julian.football_app;

    import java.util.List;

    interface FeedSource {

        List<RSSItem> getFeed();

}






<code>
```

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// //MockFeedSource.java

package com.julian.football_app;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class MockFeedSource implements FeedSource {

```
public List<RSSItem> getFeed() {

    RSSItem item;
    final List<RSSItem> items = new ArrayList<RSSItem>();
    item = new RSSItem("Android Workshop er gøy", "http://www.ap.no", " this is the desc", "");
    items.add(item);
    item = new RSSItem("Android Workshop er gøy 2", "http://www.ap.no", "this is the desc", "");
    items.add(item);
    item = new RSSItem("Android Workshop er gøy3", "http://www.ap.no", "this is the desc", "");
    items.add(item);
    return items;

}
```

}

```
</code>



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// NewsParser.java

    package com.julian.football_app;

    import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
    import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
    import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
    import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.text.ParseException;
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Date;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Locale;


    class NewsParser extends DefaultHandler {

        public static SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
        private String urlString;
        private RssFeed rssFeed;
        private StringBuilder text;
        private Item item;
        private boolean imgStatus;

        public NewsParser(String url) {
            this.urlString = url;
            this.text = new StringBuilder();
        }

        public void parse() {

            InputStream urlInputStream = null;
            SAXParserFactory spf;
            SAXParser sp;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(this.urlString);
                urlInputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                InputSource is = new InputSource(urlInputStream);
                is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

                spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                if (spf != null) {
                    sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    sp.parse(is, this);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (urlInputStream != null) urlInputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        }

        public RssFeed getFeed() {
            return (this.rssFeed);
        }

        public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
                                 Attributes attributes) {
            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("channel"))
                this.rssFeed = new RssFeed();
            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item") && (this.rssFeed != null)) {
                this.item = new Item();
                this.rssFeed.addItem(this.item);
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image") && (this.rssFeed != null))
                this.imgStatus = true;
        }

        public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) {
            if (this.rssFeed == null)
                return;

            if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
                this.item = null;

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("image"))
                this.imgStatus = false;

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                if (this.item != null) this.item.title = this.text.toString().trim();
                else if (this.imgStatus) this.rssFeed.imageTitle = this.text.toString().trim();
                else this.rssFeed.title = this.text.toString().trim();
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                if (this.item != null) this.item.link = this.text.toString().trim();
                else if (this.imgStatus) this.rssFeed.imageLink = this.text.toString().trim();
                else this.rssFeed.link = this.text.toString().trim();
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                if (this.item != null) this.item.description = this.text.toString().trim();
                else this.rssFeed.description = this.text.toString().trim();
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("url") && this.imgStatus)
                this.rssFeed.imageUrl = this.text.toString().trim();

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("language"))
                this.rssFeed.language = this.text.toString().trim();

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("generator"))
                this.rssFeed.generator = this.text.toString().trim();

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("copyright"))
                this.rssFeed.copyright = this.text.toString().trim();

            else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate") && (this.item != null)) {
                try {
                    this.item.pubDate = sdf.parse(this.text.toString().trim());
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException();
                }
            } else if (qName.equalsIgnoreCase("category") && (this.item != null))
                this.rssFeed.addItem(this.text.toString().trim(), this.item);

            this.text.setLength(0);
        }

        public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) {
            this.text.append(ch, start, length);
        }

        public static class RssFeed {
            public String title;
            public String description;
            public String link;
            public String language;
            public String generator;
            public String copyright;
            public String imageUrl;
            public String imageTitle;
            public String imageLink;

            private ArrayList<Item> items;
            private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>> category;

            public void addItem(Item item) {
                if (this.items == null)
                    this.items = new ArrayList<Item>();
                this.items.add(item);
            }

            public void addItem(String category, Item item) {
                if (this.category == null)
                    this.category = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Item>>();
                if (!this.category.containsKey(category))
                    this.category.put(category, new ArrayList<Item>());
                this.category.get(category).add(item);
            }

            public ArrayList<Item> getItems() {
                return items;
            }
        }

        public static class Item implements Comparable<Item> {
            public String title;
            public String description;
            public String link;
            public Date pubDate;
            private String url;
            private String imageUrl;

            public String toString() {
                return (this.title + ": ");
            }

            public int compareTo(Item o) {
                return (int) (o.pubDate.getTime() - pubDate.getTime());
            }

            public Date getPubDate() {
                return pubDate;
            }

            public String getDescription() {
                return description;
            }


            public String getTitle() {
                return title;
            }

            public String getUrl() {
                return url;
            }

            public String getimageUrl() {
                return imageUrl;
            }


        }
    }





package com.julian.football_app;

import com.julian.football_app.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class RSSActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main2);

        ListView rssItemList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rssListview);
        FeedSource feedSource = new HttpFeedSource();
        RSSItemAdapter adapter = new RSSItemAdapter(this, R.layout.rssitem, feedSource.getFeed());
        rssItemList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


}

/////////RssItem

    package com.julian.football_app;

    import java.util.Date;

    class RSSItem {

        private String url;
        private String title;
        private String description;
        private String imageUrl;
        private Date pubDate;

        public RSSItem() {
        }

        public RSSItem(String url, String title, String description, String imageUrl) {
            this.url = url;
            this.title = title;
            this.description = description;
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;

        }


        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDesc(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public void setImageUrl(String imageUrl) {
            this.imageUrl = imageUrl;
        }
        public String getimageUrl() {
            return imageUrl;
        }
        public void setpubDate(Date pubDate){
            this.pubDate = pubDate;
        }
        public Date getpubDate(){
            return pubDate;
        }

    }

////////////////// RssItemAdaptor

    package com.julian.football_app;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import java.util.List;

    import com.julian.football_app.R;

    class RSSItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<RSSItem> {

        private final Context context;

        public RSSItemAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
                List<RSSItem> items) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, items);
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            if (v == null) {
                LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.rssitem, null);
            }
            final RSSItem item = getItem(position);
            TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);
            TextView desc = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.description);
            TextView url = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.url);

            // this is what is viewed
            title.setText(item.getTitle());
            desc.setText(item.getDescription());
            url.setText(item.getimageUrl());
            return v;

        }

    }

///This is the button i want to display the Rss Feed
package com.julian.football_app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

    public class Menu extends Activity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.menu);

            //setting the buttons
            Button btnews1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.news_1);
            btnews1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent news1intent = new Intent(Menu.this, news_1.class);
                    Menu.this.startActivity(news1intent);   
                }
            });
```

Thank you for looking at my code... It would be much appreciated if someone could help me :) (i know its says news_1.class in the intent.. its only cuz i tried everything and went back to original state..)

These are the errors that appear in the LogCat:

```
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1508)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1384)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3190)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.julian.football_app.Menu$1.onClick(Menu.java:24)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3460)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:13955)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4340)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: So... where's this 'news' activity exactly? And *if* it's anywhere, did you not forget to add it to your manifest? As suggested below: look in LogCat for the exception details - that'll tell you more about the origin of the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the app is experiencing an exception. To find the cause you need to use LogCat to look at the exception details, which will show you where in your code there is a problem.

Comment: No errors come up in the LogCat which is weird.. would it help if i sent u link to my dropbox with the project in it?? i could also send the working RSS project in the same folder??

Comment: You said you see an error "Unfortunately football app has stopped". In that case there WILL be exception details in the LogCat output. I'm happy to answer questions on StackOverflow, but I'm unable to debug your app for you.

Comment: ok there are a few lol:

03-23 13:54:16.118: E/AndroidRuntime(553): FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: If you want people to help you I suggest you post the entire exception stack trace into your question. the single line you've posted only says where the error occurred, not what the error is.

Comment: ok i have posted the whole error stack in the question.. Sorry!!

Comment: The stack trace you've posted doesn't include the EXCEPTION. In there will be a statement of exactly what error occured. What you've posted just describes WHERE.

Answer (score 0):

See how your application goes off the rails right around:

```
E/AndroidRuntime(553): at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3297) 03-23 13:54:16.118: 
E/AndroidRuntime(553): at com.julian.football_app.Menu$1.onClick(Menu.java:24) 03-23 13:54:16.118:
```

My feeling is this isn't about the RSS at all.  I think you need to fix the Intent navigation between the Activities in your application.  You might try blocking out all the behavior from your Activities (comment out the interesting bits of `onCreate()` or whatever) and make sure you can navigate smoothly between Activities.  Then re-enable the Activities and make sure they don't blow up when you enter them.

See also MH's comment about checking that all Activities are in your Manifest.

And take out that line that says:

```
import com.julian.football_app.R;
```

If you can't get your code to compile without including a .R, then you're doing something wrong.  Try saving all the source files, deleting the contents of your `gen` directory, and selecting `Project > Clean`.